# MySQL ORDER BY TIMESTAMPDIFF TWO columns IN IF

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some problem with sorting in my query.

So, I need first display orders which have the difference between current time and column in the table(remind_date) must be (-70 - 0) ASC.
If remindDAteDIFf is not in my range than order By status_updated DESC in other situation order by (status_updated) DESC.

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,remind_date, NOW()) as remindDAteDIFf,
order_id, remind_date, status_id, status_updated 
FROM s_order
ORDER BY IF(remindDAteDIFf BETWEEN -70 AND 0, remind_date, status_updated) DESC;
```

So I got these results [image]

Which is good, but I need sort field remindDAteDIFf by ASC and status_updated BY DESC. (First need display remindDAteFf = -16 and then -28)

I tried:

```
IF(remindDAteDIFf BETWEEN -70 AND 0, remind_date ASC, status_updated DESC)
```

But I had got error which said that query is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

I think you want three keys in the `order by`:

```
ORDER BY (remindDAteDIFf BETWEEN -70 AND 0) DESC,  -- put these first
         (CASE WHEN remindDAteDIFf BETWEEN -70 AND 0 THEN remind_date END) ASC,
         status_updated DESC;
```

The first key puts the "recent" values first.  The second orders just those by `remind_date`.  The third orders the rest by `status_updated`.

Comment: Thank for replay. Unfortunately - it sort first all data by remindDAteDIFf DESC and only then by  status_updated. While I need composite order - if remindDAteDIFf is not in my range than order By status_updated DESC

Comment: "I need first display orders which have the difference between current time and column in the table(remind_date) must be (-60 - 0) ASC in other situation order by (status_updated) DESC."  This answer does what I interpret your question is asking for.  I left the "70" in instead of "60" because that is how your code is phrased.

Comment: Well, maybe I wrong explain what I need) I corrected little bit description

Comment: @YuriiChmil . . . If you do so, you will invalidate this answer, which attracks downvotes.  That's rude.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use minus to opposite the `desc`:

```
ORDER BY IF(
    remindDAteDIFf BETWEEN -70 AND 0,
    0 - unix_timestamp(remind_date),
    unix_timestamp(status_updated)) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I find solutions:

```
IF(remindDateDiff BETWEEN -70 AND 0, remindDateDiff, -71) DESC , status_updated DESC
```